# git clone bad line length error with random characters

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to clone my gitlab project on my companies computer. I therefore have to use their proxy which I set up in git.

When I try to clone the Repo I have to disable SSL verification.

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://url.to.project.git
```

This works fine for very small repos. If I want to clone a bigger repo (~140MB), the cloning starts but after a random amount of time (sometimes at 5% sometimes at up to 50%) an error accures

> remote: Counting objects: 913, done.
>
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (766/766), done.
>
> fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: o{aT022 KiB/s
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

The crazy part is, every time I run the clone I get different random characters as error. Sometimes even unreadable hieroglyphs.

Cloning the same project works fine on my private laptop.

Comment: This means your proxy has a bug.  It's introducing trash into the data stream, or dropping data from the data stream.

Comment: Thats unfortunate since my company won't be fixing this anytime soon. Does anyone have an idea how to bypass this?

Comment: Build a TCP protocol (with checksums and retransmissions) atop the proxy? :-) (I'm sort of kidding, but also sort of serious. It's been done...)